# Binary classification problem with datasets that fall into concentric circles

Tags: python, matplotlib, classification

The `make_circles()` function generates a binary classification problem with datasets that fall into concentric circles.

```py
data, label = ds.make_circles(n_samples=1000, factor=.4, noise=0.05)

# Lets visualize the dataset
reds = label == 0
blues = label == 1
plt.scatter(data[reds, 0], data[reds, 1], c="red", s=20, edgecolor='k')
plt.scatter(data[blues, 0], data[blues, 1], c="blue", s=20, edgecolor='k')
plt.show()
```

How to implement a single layer neural network to classify this data in python?

Comment: can you please elaborate your problem ? what is your dataset ? and other things

Comment: @Vaibhavgusain the data set is the one i have written the code for.
my task is to train a neural network on this data to classify it. 
my neural network should consist of one hidden layer only. and activation functions can be used as per choice

Comment: what is ds and how does make cricles make data ?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest Neural Network made with `Keras` will look like this:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=2, init='uniform'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, init='uniform'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, init='uniform'))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd,metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

model.fit(data, pd.get_dummies(label),nb_epoch=500,batch_size=data.shape[0])


model.evaluate(data, pd.get_dummies(label))

predictions=np.argmax(model.predict(data),axis=1)  #OR

predictions=model.predict_classes(data)

# Epoch 500/500
#1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 5us/step - loss: 0.6897 - acc: 0.9990
```

OUTPUT of Classification by Neural Network:

[image: Output Neural Network]

Remember you will have do adjust Neural Network architecture and hyperparameters:

[image: Neural Network Adjustements]